# How to mount a Ring flood light cam when you have no junction box and a hole with wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, outdoor

I am trying to mount a Ring floodlight cam but the mounting plate that comes included will not secure tight against the vinyl square box. What is the best solution going forward? Should install this weather box on the actual vinyl square box? I want to avoid cutting any vinyl if possible.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Is this new vinyl siding over old siding with a misaligned j-box behind the new siding?

Comment: Nope never installed any new vinyl siding, we have the same siding ever since.

Comment: I see the cable's outer insulation there in the wall.  Can you pull it out so it extends at least half an inch outside the wall?  If so, perhaps there was an outdoor-rated junction box surface mounted there.   The Ring thing can mount on such a box, and the cable can be secured to the back of it.    If you can pull it out far enough.

Answer (score 3):

What you've got right now violates code. There are some light fixtures with an integral box, but the cable here looks like the sheath is cut off way inside the wall. No good.

What you should be able to do is:

- Remove the existing siding mounting block
- Cut as needed in order to install a proper box. Metal is my preference, but plastic will do. The key is to get a box of the proper depth such that the existing cable can reach *with its sheath* to just inside the new box.
- Install a new siding mounting block
- Install the Ring device on the mounting block

There are a number of varieties of boxes available. Exactly what you will need (round or octagon vs. single gang rectangle, etc.) will depend on the Ring.

Comment: If the floodlight doesn't come with a gasket, I'd also consider running some foam rubber weatherstripping tape (Frost King, etc.) around the back of the mounting plate (leave a gap at the bottom).